# Working with multiple properties of array VB .net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list

I'm working on a program to parse a file name based on a drag drop, and process and remove a list of words that may be found in the file. I had the program working, but in a not so elegant manner, as well as a manner that would introduce issues later on in the program.

I'm trying create a list of a custom class or structure.

Here's what I have:

```
Public Class moviePath
   Public currentPath As String
   Public currentNameExt As String
   Public currentName As String
   Public currentExt As String
   Public correctedName As String
   Public correctYear As String
End Class
```

The issue is then when I attempt to create a usable variable based on this:

```
Dim workingList as New List(Of moviePath)
```

I'm left with no good way to correctly add data to the list using subs such as this:

```
Sub scanParent(ByVal sDir As String)
    Dim f As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Try

        For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(sDir)

            workingList(i).currentName = (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))
            workingList(i).currentNameExt = (Path.GetFileName(f))
            workingList(i).currentPath = (Path.GetFullPath(f))

            i += 1
        Next
    Catch excpt As System.Exception
        MessageBox.Show("It didn't work " & excpt.ToString)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Hopefully those tidbits make sense. `scanParent` sub is called passing the path to a folder as the argument (ie C\somefolder) and I intend to populate an array of sorts with information about files and folders. My reasoning is that I would like to be able to remove words from movie titles, in order use a opensource library (not sure if correct language) that parses IMDB to pull in movie info.

The main thing that I need is for each item in the class moviePath to be addressable and tied to each other item at that position in the list.

EDIT: ie. `moviePath(0).currentPath` would be in reference to the same file `moviePath(0).currentName`

Comment: You should be using the List(Of T).Add method: `workingList.Add(<item>)`

Comment: you could also pass the directory item (f) to MoviePath in the constructor and let it create itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(sDir)
    dim info as new moviePath

    info.currentName = (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))
    info.currentNameExt = (Path.GetFileName(f))
    info.currentPath = (Path.GetFullPath(f))

    workingList.add(info)
Next
```

Comment: Since it looks like `workingList` is global, you should probably call `workingList.Clear()` before the for/each loop also, just to make sure it's empty if you are calling this sub multiple times (from a button click for example).  This may not be needed if you actually intend to call it multiple times for different paths or only once for the entire life of the application.

Comment: I had actually thought of that, it's just in a section of code I hadn't shown

Comment: In this instance, the sub is only called initially when a folder or file is dragged onto the program. So in theory, you'd drag a folder of movies, It'll clean up the name to a point where it can be searched, and the rename using the exact correct name and year. IE: I drag in a file called tHe.AvENGers.mkv, and it should (when finished) spit out The Avengers (2012).mkv which is much nicer in a library

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [List(T).Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) method for this.

```
Sub scanParent(ByVal sDir As String)
    Dim f As String
    Try

        For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(sDir)
            Dim newPath As New moviePath()

            newPath.currentName = (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))
            newPath.currentNameExt = (Path.GetFileName(f))
            newPath.currentPath = (Path.GetFullPath(f))

            workingList.Add(newPath)
        Next
    Catch excpt As System.Exception
        MessageBox.Show("It didn't work " & excpt.ToString)

    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Plutonix.  In addition to the fix by Bradley, also pass the FileName to your movePath class like this:

```
Public Class moviePath

    Public Sub New(ByVal FullFilePath As String)
        Me.currentPath = FullFilePath
        Me.currentName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FullFilePath)
        Me.currentNameExt = Path.GetFileName(FullFilePath)
    End Sub

    Public currentPath As String
    Public currentNameExt As String
    Public currentName As String
    Public currentExt As String
    Public correctedName As String
    Public correctYear As String

End Class
```

Now your loop becomes simply:

```
For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(sDir)
    workingList.add(New moviePath(f))
Next
```

Comment: Awesome! I incorporated that into my code as it definitely helps clean it up a bit.